# Difference between contradiction and paradox?

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

In multivalued logic one can distinguish at contradictions (of the type $P\wedge\neg P$) and paradoxes (of type $P\leftrightarrow \neg P$). How about in mathematics? Does the appearance of contradictions and paradoxes (in proofs) have different quality or "color" despite the logical equivalence?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK: Contradictions are used in proofs under the definition you have stated. The word paradox tends to be used to describe mathematical phenomena that while not necessarily entailing contradictions (the paradox may even be a theorem), are nonetheless in conflict with intuition. e.g. [Russell's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) (shows that some easily defined "sets" don't exist), [Banach-Tarski paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) (contradicts our sense of the way that solids behave in euclidean space).

Comment: You can add [Skolem's paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-skolem/) as an example of a counter-intuitive result that is true (in the sense of proved from accepted principles). About[Russell's paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/) thing are more subtle : "naïve set theory assumes the so-called naïve or unrestricted *Comprehension Axiom*. [...] from the assumption of this axiom, Russell's contradiction follows." Thus, we can say that it is the proof of the contradictory nature of the previous principle.